# How to make a method generic to work with LocalDate and LocalDateTime?

Tags: java-8, polymorphism, java-time, jsr310

I have a Java method as below:

```
private static boolean isDateBetweenRange(DataSet obj, MyClass dataSource, ConditionContext context) {
    FilterContext fc = dataSource.getData();

    LocalDate dateFieldToCheck = obj.getDate(fc.getDateField()).toInstant()
                                   .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate minDate = fc.getMinDateValue();
    LocalDate maxDate = fc.getMaxDateValue();

    if (minDate == null || maxDate == null) {
        minDate = context.getStartDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                    .toLocalDate();
        maxDate = context.getEndDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                    .toLocalDate();
    }

    boolean result = (dateFieldToCheck.isAfter(minDate) || dateFieldToCheck.isEqual(minDate))
            && (dateFieldToCheck.isBefore(maxDate) || dateFieldToCheck.isEqual(maxDate));

    return result;
}
```

I want to make the same logic for `LocalDateTime` also. It's gonna be the exact same code for `LocalDateTime` if I overload the method.

How can make the method generic to work with `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` using Generics or any other mechanism?

How can I make `context.getXXXDate()... toLocalDate()` or `toLocalDateTime()` a common code based on type I have?

Comment: First I don’t think you can, or at least not completely, though it’s possible to factor out the shared logic. Second, it’s not really clear. Where have you got either a `LocalDate` or a `LocalDateTime` from? Can `fc.getMinDateValue()` return either? If so, what is its declared return type?

Comment: As an aside, there’s a nasty corner case: if someone changes your JVM’s time zone setting while your method runs, you can get surprising results. I suggest you call `ZoneId.systemDefault()` only once and keep the returned zone in a variable that you use every time you need it. This way you are sure you use the same zone in all the `atZone()` calls.

Answer (score 6):

The `TemporalAccessor` interface can be used to do this. However, be aware that `TemporalAccessor` is an advanced interface that should not be used outside low-level utility code.

```
boolean api(TemporalAccessor temporal1, TemporalAccessor temporal2) {
  LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.from(temporal1);
  LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.from(temporal2);
  return ...;
}
```

This code will now accept `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` and , `ZonedDateTime`.

As mentioned in the comments, it is vital to only call `ZoneId.systemDefault()` once within a piece of business logic, as the value can change.

Answer (score 3):

Well... `LocalDateTime` is an immutable composition of `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`. It has methods `toLocalDate()` and `toLocalTime()` with which you can "decompose it". The opposite is also true - you can also pretty easily create a composition - see `LocalDate.atTime(LocalTime)`.

It seems natural to me that if you consider time in your logic your extracted API-s should accept `LocalDateTime`. In the suspicious cases :) in which you want to feed for some reason this API with `LocalDate`-s you may explicitly use, for example, `LocalDate.atStartOfDay`. Something as this:

```
boolean api(LocalDate aDate, LocalDate anotherDate)
{
    return this.api(aDate.atStartOfDay(), anotherDate.atStartOfDay());
}

boolean api(LocalDateTime aDateTime, LocalDateTime anotherDateTime)
{
    return ...;
}
```

Which seems a bit ugly though but will still work pretty fine, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method receives a `java.time.temporal.Temporal` as parameter (or a `TemporalAccessor` as [suggested by @JodaStephen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699055/7605325)). This code works for both.

I must admit that I'd prefer to do it like [@Lachezar Balev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44696469/7605325) is suggesting, but anyway, here's an alternative.

As a `Temporal` can be of any type (`LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, etc), but you want just `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime`, I'm doing the following:

- try to create a `LocalDateTime` first: it requires more fields than a `LocalDate` (hour/minute/second), so if it can be created, it's the prefered type
- if it can't be created, I catch the respective exception and try to create a `LocalDate`

Another detail is that I also simplified your comparison:

```
dateFieldToCheck.isAfter(minDate) || dateFieldToCheck.isEqual(minDate)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
! dateFieldToCheck.isBefore(minDate)
```

And a similar simplification was done when comparing with `maxDate`:

```
public boolean check(Temporal dateFieldToCheck, Temporal minDate, Temporal maxDate) {
    // try to get as LocalDateTime
    try {
        LocalDateTime dtCheck = LocalDateTime.from(dateFieldToCheck);
        LocalDateTime dtMin = LocalDateTime.from(minDate);
        LocalDateTime dtMax = LocalDateTime.from(maxDate);

        return (!dtCheck.isBefore(dtMin)) && (!dtCheck.isAfter(dtMax));
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        // exception: one of the Temporal objects above doesn't have all fields required by a LocalDateTime
        // trying a LocaDate instead
        LocalDate dCheck = LocalDate.from(dateFieldToCheck);
        LocalDate dMin = LocalDate.from(minDate);
        LocalDate dMax = LocalDate.from(maxDate);

        return (!dCheck.isBefore(dMin)) && (!dCheck.isAfter(dMax));
    }
}
```

Now you can call this method with both a `LocalDate` and a `LocalDateTime`:

```
check(LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 19), LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 18), LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 29)); // true
check(LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 17), LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 18), LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 29)); // false
check(LocalDateTime.of(2017, 6, 29, 9, 0), LocalDateTime.of(2017, 6, 29, 8, 0), LocalDateTime.of(2017, 6, 29, 11, 0)); // true
check(LocalDateTime.of(2017, 6, 29, 7, 0), LocalDateTime.of(2017, 6, 29, 8, 0), LocalDateTime.of(2017, 6, 29, 11, 0)); // false
```

---

You can extend the code to recognize other types, if you need (such as `LocalTime`).

You could also add another parameter indicating what type will be used, like this:

```
public boolean check(Temporal dateFieldToCheck, Temporal minDate, Temporal maxDate, int type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            // try to get as LocalDateTime
            LocalDateTime dtCheck = LocalDateTime.from(dateFieldToCheck);
            LocalDateTime dtMin = LocalDateTime.from(minDate);
            LocalDateTime dtMax = LocalDateTime.from(maxDate);

            return (!dtCheck.isBefore(dtMin)) && (!dtCheck.isAfter(dtMax));
        case 2:
            // trying a LocaDate instead
            LocalDate dCheck = LocalDate.from(dateFieldToCheck);
            LocalDate dMin = LocalDate.from(minDate);
            LocalDate dMax = LocalDate.from(maxDate);

            return (!dCheck.isBefore(dMin)) && (!dCheck.isAfter(dMax));
        // ... and so on
    }

    // invalid type, return false?
    return false;
}
```

So you could call it with a `ZonedDateTime` and force it to use a `LocalDate` (then you could adapt your code and call this method with the objects you've got from `atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())`):

```
ZonedDateTime z1 = obj.getDate(fc.getDateField()).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime z2 = context.getStartDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime z3 = context.getEndDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
check(z1, z2, z3, 2);
```

This code also works with different types:

```
ZonedDateTime z1 = ...
LocalDate d = ...
LocalDateTime dt = ...
// converts all to LocalDate
System.out.println(check(z1, dt, d, 2));
```

---

**PS:** of course you could create an `Enum` instead of an `int` to define the type. Or use a `Class<? extends Temporal>` to directly indicate the type:

```
public boolean check(Temporal dateFieldToCheck, Temporal minDate, Temporal maxDate, Class<? extends Temporal> type) {
    if (type == LocalDate.class) {
        // code for LocalDate (use LocalDate.from() as above)
    }
    if (type == LocalDateTime.class) {
        // code for LocalDateTime (use LocalDateTime.from() as above)
    }
}

// convert all objects to LocalDate
check(z1, dt, d, LocalDate.class);
```